# python syntax error declaring variable

Tags: python, variables

I'm new to python. Here's my file:

**contiguous.py:**

```
def fillArray(len, val):
    var arr = [], i
    for i = 0; i < len; i++:
        arr.append(val)
    return arr
```

I try to execute:

```
$ python contiguous.py
  File "contiguous.py", line 2
    var arr = [], i
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ python -V
Python 3.6.0
```

Why the error? What am I missing?

Comment: Because that isn't python...

Comment: Well, since Python doesn't have variable declarations, I would hope you are getting an error...

Comment: Seriously, take a look at the official [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It's very good, especially if you already have programming experience.

Comment: I think you should take a look at some [Python basics](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Comment: @ChihebNexus that's a rather odd "basics" tutorial. it is out of date, too. `numarray`? Really?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i didn't read it lol The first link from Google. I'll edit the link. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free tutoring service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to declare a variable to use it in Python. You just instantiate. So you would want to write just `arr = []` and nothing for `i`. Furthermore, your loop syntax is incorrect. You should write `for i in range(len)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your function in Python is:

```
def fillArray(len, val):
    arr = []
    for _ in range(len):
        arr.append(val)
    return arr
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def fillArray(len, val):
    return [val] * len
```

Which are both dangerous if `val` is [`mutable`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html): Python is [pass by assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/3579910), so if you try to make an array of empty lists, via `fillArray(len, [])`, you will have a bad day.

Comment: I prefer the term "call by sharing"... because sharing is caring!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Maybe that should become the official term. Fredrik Lundh's effbot article [call by object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) mentions call by sharing as a synonym... ultimately that may be a better source for someone who may be confused by the topic.

Comment: Well, it is the term used by Barbara Liskov, when she invented it for [CLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLU_(programming_language)). But it is a rather unused term. Indeed, in Java, they just say call-by-value!  Other things introduced in that language are iterators and constructors!

Answer (score 0):

There is no var keyword in python. Simply remove that.

Variables are set with:

```
variable_x = []
```

Also, the way you set more than one variable per line in python is:

```
variable_x, i = [], 0
```

Also, your loop looks wrong. It should be:

```
for i in range(len):
```

Comment: Changed declared to set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the keyword `var`. To make `arr` an array, just do:

```
arr = []
```

Variables in python don't have types, only objects do. The type of a variable at any given moment is the type of the object they refer at that moment. So the line above initializes `arr` to an empty list, effectively making `arr` a list too. Also, some other considerations about your code: you are trying to fill an array with a value. There's a **much** easier way to do it:

```
arr = [val] * len
```

In this case you don't even need to do `arr=[]`, your whole function can be replaced by the line above.

Comment: `[val] * len` is usually a bad idea, especially for new programmers, because it only works if `val` is immutable.